# Debugging causes an error "Conflicting handlers for org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui.toggle.comment"

Tags: eclipse

I'm a little baffled as I have used eclipse to debug PHP with XDebug on other machines.  I am now setting up a new machine and when I try to use the debugger I get the following  error:

```
eclipse.buildId=M20130204-1200
java.version=1.7.0_21
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_CA
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64

Error
Sat May 25 13:28:14 EDT 2013
Conflicting handlers for org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui.toggle.comment: {org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui.internal.handlers.ToggleLineCommentHandler@18e2184c} vs {org.eclipse.php.internal.ui.actions.PHPToggleLineCommentHandler@23a93257}
```

Any words of wisdom? 
Kate

Answer (score 0):

If you use Eclipse Juno SR2, there is a possible solution here:

http://piece-framework.com/news

> Release Date: 2013-03-19 What's New in MakeGood 2.4.0 Fixes an error
>   "Conflicting handlers for org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui.toggle.comment ...".
>
> (Issue 27)
>
> Eclipse Juno SR2 (4.2.2) with PDT 3.1.2 causes an error "Conflicting
>   handlers for org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui.toggle.comment:
>   {org.eclipse.php.internal.ui.actions.PHPToggleLineCommentHandler@f6ef40a}
>   vs
>   {org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui.internal.handlers.ToggleLineCommentHandler@3d57c470}"
>   when an PHP editor is activated. This is not a defect of MakeGood, but
>   it will be fixed by MakeGood.

Comment: Hmm, I didn't have to install MakeGood to get XDebug to work in the past.